# what happens if we install two boot images in a pendrive?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, live-usb

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 image in my 16 GB Moserbaer pendrive. i am willing to install another image in it with out losing this 12.04.

i'm using Universal USB installer 1.9.4.3.

Thank you.

Comment: Well this is totally a thing to do practical. It will not harm any thing if you try it by your self.. We would like to know your experience, so you can share it here. If you don't get any option to format the USB while making bootable of other image then it will make your task easier and you'll get the result also.. Mean while you can check [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it) :)

Comment: Thank you very much. your link was very Helpfull. Ill try that.

Yes this software "Universal USB intaler" has an option not to format the pendrive and ill try some more tricks and i will surly share my experience, and if it succeeds, ill share the steps also. thank You again.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/121116/trying-different-flavors-of-ubuntu-from-a-usb-drive/121125#121125

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the merging of iso files it worked

both the images working fine.... i merged

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Hiren's Bootcd 15

And it looks like the below while booting..

```
              MultiCD - Created Oct 19, 2013

Boot from hard drive
--> Hiren's BootCD - main menu
--> Ubuntu (32-bit) 12.04.2 Menu
Memtest86+ v4.20
```

The same happened, when i tryed to write another image without formating the

pendrive With **"Universal USB installer"**

The same thing Happened.. i downloaded it from UBUNTU site itself..

this is my first post.. 

Thank you..